# Starting an intent in onPictureTaken causes Eclipse to crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-camera

I am attempting to make an android app where I take an image with the camera and send that image to another activity to be edited and whatnot. I try to do this by sending a byte array by intent like this:

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhotoEditor.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

I am testing this with my Lenovo IdeaTab a3000-F. About a third of the time this runs without problem. The rest of the time my program freezes (it does not close or give a popup - it just stops doing anything) and then Eclipse gives this message on Console DDMS:

```
[ddms] Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
```

and then if I try to run any apps on my tablet it gives this message on Console Android:

```
   [] Failed to install *.apk on device *:
   [] timeout Launch canceled!
```

What I have done to fix this is:

1. Close Eclipse and disconnect my tablet
2. End task of adb.exe in task manager
3. Type `adb start-server` in command prompt
4. Reopen Eclipse

--at this point the eclipse errors go away, but my tablet in not recognized if I try to use it--

1. Turn my tablet on and off again and reconnect it

After doing this I can run apps on my tablet again, but Eclipse will just crash again if I run that part of the app.

So my question is: why does this cause Eclipse to have errors and how can I prevent them from happening? Also, if there is another way to do this that doesn't involve byte arrays at all that would be great, but I am still looking to find out why this causes a problem.

Here is some additional information that may help:

- The data array has a length of about 100000, however, if instead of passing the data array to the intent I pass a new byte array of even larger size I either don't get an error or if its just enormous I get a different error that crashes my program but not Eclipse
- I re-downloaded the android adt today so I have whatever that version is
- The other activity does not do anything with the data on the intent, or even retrieve it
- I have the driver for my tablet, USB debugging is enabled, it is connected by MTP, and my project has debuggable set to true
- after the program freezes, if I close it I can't open it again and if I try to uninstall it nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Intents are designed to carry messages or small data with them, passing byte[] thru intent is causing the error.Getting the byte array from intent in the onCreate() of PhotoEditor class may be causing the app to freeze.
In onPictureTaken(), you can write your byteArray to a file and then pass the uri of this file thru intent.In the second activity,ie,PhotoEditor load the image using this uri.Thus you can avoid passing byte arrays using intent.
Hope this may help you.